# How to Keep Data fields When Recaptcha is Invalid

Tags: php, recaptcha

My php contact form is working fine and I just need help on **how to keep the data fields when recaptcha is incorrect or invalid.** Where do I need to ad more script to accomplish this?
Thank you very much for any answers. I am still new at php. This is ALL IN ONE PAGE Called: CONTACTFORM.php

```
<?php


require_once('recaptchalib.php');

$publickey = "xxxxxxxxx";
$privatekey = "xxxxxxxx";
$error = false;
$message = '';



if (isset($_POST['send'])){     
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid)
    {
        $error = true;      
        $message = 'Invalid Captcha Please try again';
    }

      if(!$error)
    {
        $emailTitle = 'Email from website!';
        $emailAddress = 'peace@hotmail.com';

        /* Gathering Data Variables */

        $emailField = $_POST['email'];
        $phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
        $nameField = $_POST['name'];
        $subjectField = $_POST['subject'];
        $messageField = $_POST['message'];

        $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $emailField <br />
Phone: $phoneField <br />
Name: $nameField <br />
Subject: $subjectField <br />
Message: $messageField <br />
EOD;
        $headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $success = mail("$emailAddress", "$emailTitle", "$body", "$headers");

        $message = "Thank you! Your message has been sent.";
    }
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="contactform.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="email" class="titulos">Email: </label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" maxlength="50" /> 
            *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="phone" class="titulos">Phone: </label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="35" maxlength="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="name" class="titulos">Name:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="35" maxlength="30" />
            *</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><label for="subject" class="titulos">Subject:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="35" maxlength="60" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="top"><label for="message" class="titulos">Message:</label></td>
          <td align="left"><p>
            <textarea name="message" cols="27" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
            *</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left"> 
          <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>


</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td align="right"><label for="reset"></label></td>
          <td align="left"><label for="send"></label>
          <input name="send" type="submit" id="send" onclick="MM_validateForm('email','','RisEmail','name','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send Email" /> <label for="reset"></label>
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset form" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="left" class="content">(*) Are Required fields</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><?php echo $message; ?>
          </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: you fill the value field from the POST\GET array

Comment: Hint: `<input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="35" maxlength="50" value="..." />` Input elements have a `value` attribute, which you can use to pre-populate them with data. Please try to take it from here.

Comment: It's not a good idea to insert unescaped user data into the email's body.

Answer (score 5):

You could set it in the "value" attribute of your input fields.  Something like

```
<input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : ''); ?>" />
```

Comment: Is there really a need for the if? why not just echo the POST, it will be empty when not send.

Comment: @corubba Because that'll trigger an `E_NOTICE`, which will [make debugging all the harder](http://kunststube.net/isset/). You *are* developing with error reporting turned on, right?

Comment: @declan Don't forget to HTML escape user input!

Comment: @deceze I develop with error reporting, but don't mind notices, cause they don't break the execution nor treats PHP to open the error log. Only usefull for debugging imho. And I'm quiet don't get why escape raw input that will not be proceed or saved, but simply echoed. Won't it be displayed as literal than rendered?

Comment: @corubba So you enjoy wading through useless error messages to identify real errors from "false" errors? Why are you making your life so hard? And you *always* escape user input, because you never know what's in it. Simplest case it just breaks your HTML syntax and makes it impossible for the user to submit the form again, worst case you're enabling some form of XSS through other side effects.

Comment: @corubba - You could certainly leave the `isset` out if you don't mind the warning messages.  Personally I find it makes a lot of unnecessary noise.

Comment: @corubba That raw input (coming from the user) will be inserted to your HTML. The user can send anything.